# yii2 returning records from a database table

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have the following table which has a column with values saved by being separated by a comma
That is

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

So at the end i achieve something like this

```
first row      1,2,3,4
second row     2,3,5
third row      1,4,5
```

The rows have an attribute category

So i would like to return all rows having a particular value like 1

This is what i have tried

```
public function actionChecklist($categoryval)  //category is the integer value eg 1
{

    $checklistitems= TblChecklist::find()->where(
        [
            "category"=>in_array("category",[$categoryval])
        ]
    )->all();


    var_dump($checklistitems);
    die();

}
```

The above code always returns empty where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` provided that every single category is surrounded by two delimiters in your case commas i.e. `,1,2,3,4,5,` instead of `1,2,3,4,5`. Without these commas a search for say `1` will return everything with a `1` in it including stuff like `10,2,3`.

Your search parameter will also require to be surrounded by these commas:

```
$checklistitems= TblChecklist::find()
    ->where(["like", "category", ",".$categoryval.","])
    ->all();
```

However, you should probably denormalize your table by creating a junction table between checklists and categories. You should then create a relation between your checklist model and your categories model. The code above will then look something like:

```
$checklistitems= TblChecklist::find()
    ->joinWith("categories")
    ->where(["categories.id" => $categoryval])
    ->all();
```